# Using utils.R in R package building

Tags: r, build, package

Assume you are building an R package and you want to put some functions (say `internFuncA` and `internFuncB`) in the utils.R folder. You want to keep these functions internal, so the users of your package can not call them directly. Next, assume you have an *ordinary* function in your package called `foo(x, y, f)` (by *ordinary* I mean that users can call it, or better, it is not an internal function as both above) where `f` can take values function `internFuncA` or `internFuncB`. So you want the user to be to able to pass `internA` or `internB` to argument `f` of `foo` (i.e. `foo(x, y, f =  internFuncB)`. I know a file `utils.R` can be used to place auxiliary functions as per Chapter 7 section 7.2 in [R packages](https://r-pkgs.org/r.html). My question is, can I use `utils.R` to have these two functions in there? Do I need to specify something in `utils.R` to make them only internally accessible?

Comment: What is `utils.R`? Is it a file (script), or is it a directory under which you have other things? Is your directory structured like an R package is supposed to be? If you haven't yet, I suggest you read https://r-pkgs.org, there are several components required to build packages. I think what you're asking here is about whether particular functions are exported (accessible via `::`) or internal-only (accessible via `:::`).

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for `:::` this is something I did not know about.